# How to push elements to end of flexbox without changing their width

Tags: css, flexbox

I am placing some spans inside mat-toolbar which by default has display flex. Now I want some of the items on the extreme right. I use `margin-left: auto` for these elements. The problem is that these elements are stretched in order to fill the entire flexbox. What I want is some elements, followed by empty space, followed by the elements with `margin-left: auto` having their width as fit-content.

What I want :
[image]

What I'm getting:
[image]

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>Flex item</span>
  <span class="right">Flex item</span>
  <span class="right">Flex item</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
     display: flex;
     border: 1px dotted black;
        }
        
.right { margin-left: auto; }

span {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px
}
```

Comment: its not clear what do you want it to look like, can you append an img?

Comment: Without your HTML and CSS, your (expected) "*[mcve]*" code, it's hard to really offer a practical solution that doesn't involve guessing; also linking to your code elsewhere isn't a substitute for posting your (again: minimal) code here in the question.

Comment: margin auto only to the second child

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you said, I understood you wanted something like this... 
Using `flexbox` is the correct way to achieve it, but you must add some properties to make it style the way you want.

**Use:**

- `justify-content: space-between` to align the items into the extremes (left and right);
- `align-items: center` to align vertically to the center, your information on HTML.
- `Create 2 divs` to align both `divs` to the extremes.

Here is the example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toolbar {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.start-items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}

.multiple-items {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="start-items">
    <h5>
      Start Item1
    </h5>
    <h5>
      Start Item2
    </h5>
  </div>
  <div class="multiple-items">
    <h5>
      Item1
    </h5>
    <h5>
      Item2
    </h5>
    <h5>
      Item3
    </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```